# Calculus proof help

Tags: calculus

I'm really stuck on this, and not sure where to even start. Any help would be really appreciated!

Let $A := \{\,(x+1)^2 +2 : x \in \Bbb R\,\}$. Find $a,b \in \Bbb R\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that $A$ is equal to an interval $I$ with end-points $a, b$.

It also says '(Remember that you also need to prove the equality $A = I$.)'

Thank you!

Comment: Should that read $(x+1)^2+2$?

Answer (score 0):

**Claim.** $A=[2,\infty)$.

*Proof.* We need to show two things: a) If $t\in A$ then $t\ge 2$ . b) If $t\ge 2$ then $t\in A$.

a) Assume $t\in A$, say $t=(x+1)^2+2$. As squares of reals are nonnegative, we conclude $t\ge 2$ as desired.

b) Assume $t\ge 2$. Then $t-2\ge 0$ and $y^2=t-2$ has at least one solution. If $y$ is such a solution, then with $x=y-1$ we have $t=(x+1)^2+2\in A$ as desired.